# How to replace a date in a date list using SSJS in XPages

Tags: date, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a date list field and need to replace a value in the list with another value

so I have this list of type "date list"

[image]

The user enter a new value in a date field in the webpage. This new value should be added to in this case the second item in the date list, but it in the real case it should be able to be added to any position in the list

This is the inputfield where user enter a new date

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1">
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"></xp:convertDateTime>
                </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

This is the code I use in my button that should replace the date
doc is a data source on the XPage

```
var v:java.util.Vector = doc.getDocument().getItemValueDateTimeArray("TDate")
v.setElementAt(getComponent("inputText1").getValue(),1)
doc.replaceItemValue("TDate",v)
doc.save()
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, but I seem to have two problems, first the field only seem to contain one element after I save, and secondly the date that is added contain both date and time, and not only the date

This is the result after running the code

[image]

Running the same kind of code using a multivalue "text" field works fine.

how can I modify my code so that my replace operation in the date list works

Answer (score 0):

1. to set a date value without the time part
   get a DateTime object and call the function **setAnyTime()** on the NDT object and replace the item
2. to set a specific time value in a multivalue datetime field
   get the field you will get a vector with all the datetime object.
   Get the specific timedate in the vector change it and set it back to the   vector. and after that replace the item

Comment: thanks, I get #1, and setAnyTime() but can't get it to work with a datelist. #2. I do not understad what you mean "time value"? I need only the "date value"

Comment: 1. I tested that too now and I did get it to work either, will check it more 2. I mean that you need to extract the datetime object from the vector and replace it after you have changed it and replace the item with the new vector